# Gif when used as pagination loader, sometimes not displayed in image view

Tags: ios, swift, pagination, uicollectionview, gif

I am using collection view with pagination to show more data. At end of collection view I show an image view with gif file until data loads and then hide the image view. But sometimes gif doesn't load in the image view.

Please help and thanks in advance !!

I have tried changing libraries - Kingfisher, SDWebImage, ImageIO, UIImage+Gif etc. but it didn't help.
Also tried running on main thread.

```
class HorizontalScrollDealCollectionView: UICollectionView {

    private var indicator:UIImageView!
    private var offset:CGFloat = 0
    private let loaderGif  =  UIImage.gif(name: "831")

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        let frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: self.frame.height/2-15, width: 30, height: 30)
        indicator = UIImageView(frame: frame)
        indicator.image = loaderGif
        indicator.backgroundColor = .blue
        self.addSubview(indicator)
        indicator.isHidden = true
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.adjustIndicator()
    }

    func loadGifAnimatedIndicator() {
        indicator.isHidden = true
        indicator.image = loaderGif
    }

    private func adjustIndicator() {
        indicator.frame.origin.x = self.contentSize.width + (offset/2)
        let view = self.visibleCells.first
        if let scrollViewAdjuster = view as? InfiniteScrollOffsetAdjuster {
            indicator.frame.origin.y = scrollViewAdjuster.refralFrameForProgressView.height / 2 - 15
        }
        else {
            indicator.frame.origin.y = self.contentSize.height / 2 - 15;
        }
    }

    func showIndicator() {
        if indicator.isHidden == false { return }
        indicator.isHidden = false
        indicator.image = loaderGif
        indicator.startAnimating()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            self.contentInset.right = self.offset + 40
        }
    }

    func hideIndicator() {
        if indicator.isHidden { return }
        self.indicator.isHidden = true
    }

    func resetContentInset(animate:Bool = true) {
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(animate)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            self.contentInset.right = 0
        }) { (success) in
            if !animate {
                UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**In ViewController**

```
//Table View Delegate
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let homeTableViewCell = cell as? HorizontalScrollHomeTableViewCell else {
            return
        }
        homeTableViewCell.collectionView.loadGifAnimatedIndicator()
        homeTableViewCell.collectionView.reloadData()
    }

//Collection View Delegate
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let horizontalCollView = collectionView as! HorizontalScrollDealCollectionView
        let dataIndex = horizontalCollView.tableViewCellIndex!
        let data = items[dataIndex.row]
        if (indexPath.item == data.products.count - 1) && data.moreAvailable {
            horizontalCollView.showIndicator()
            data.loadMore(completion: {
                (success) in
                horizontalCollView.hideIndicator()
                if success {horizontalCollView.reloadData()}
            })
        }
    }
```

**Screenshot 1**
[image: Screenshot when gif works fine.]

****Screenshot 2**
[image: Screenshot when gif is not loaded in imageview]

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
private let loaderGif = UIImage.gif(name: "831")
```

to

```
private var loaderGif: UIImage { 
   return UIImage.gif(name: "831")
}
```

solves the issue but tableview scrolling becomes laggy/jittering.

Also did this asynchronously using DispatchQueue but didn't helped. Still scrolling hangs.

```
func loadGifAnimatedIndicator() {
  indicator.isHidden = true
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.indicator.image = self.loaderGif
  }
}
```